# How to customize the alert component in Bootstrap 5.3 using SASS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I made changes to the $primary and $secondary variables. And that changes all the components I tested like buttons, cards, navbar. But it doesn't change the color of the alerts. This is my custom.sass file:

```
$purple-dark:  #9926f0;
$purple-light:  #BB6EF5;
$pink:    #d122e3;
 
$primary:       $purple-dark;
$secondary:     $pink;
 
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

In the documentation about the alert there is a warning box, but it does not explain how to solve it. Or I could not understand!

"Heads up! As of v5.3, the Sass mixin is deprecated. Alert variants now have their CSS variables overridden in the Sass loop. alert-variant()"

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/alerts/

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?  I am struggling with it as well.